# Xamarin iOS Native - Google Maps Api Security

Tags: api, google-maps, xamarin.ios, native

I am building a Xamarin iOS Native project for a iPhone app and i am using Google Maps for creating Routes to several delivery points.

I registered for the Google Maps API but i have troubles with the security of the API key.

In my project i have installed the Nugget package for **Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps** and set the *App restrictions* to my iOS Bundle name. When initializing the MAP all works fine.

BUT we also use the Direction API for setting up routes to different points of the map. But this call function method is a HttpClient call to a JsonAsync call. The Google API denies the call because it did not work with the Bundle name because its a HtppClient Call.

The project is installed on Mobile devices so restricting with a IP address is not a option for us. No restriction AT ALL is also bad for the security.

So my question is : How do I secure this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that web services cannot work with API keys that are Android/iOS restricted. Web services are server-side and can only work with API keys that are either unrestricted or restricted by IP address.

To resolve your issue, please create a second API key to use for web service requests only.

The public docs on best practices when using API keys has also some suggestions for when IP address restrictions are impractical as with the case with mobile applications.

When using Maps Web Service APIs in these scenarios, secure your apps using one or more of the following techniques:

-proxy server

-obfuscation

-pinning

References:

https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table_sup_5
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#proxy_server